# How to ignore overflowed content with the following elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a ul-list to contain 1 figure-element in each li. 
The lower parts of the figures' img-element I hide by using overflow:hidden to the parent-element and width:100% to the img-element.

But thereby the height of the figure-element is still the "maximum" one, so I guess I need something additional to prevent that. I screenshoted it for better visualization of the problem:

[image: overflow-problem within the white gap at the bottom]

I use this code to style the li and figure-elements:

```
.rf_re1_produkt_details *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rf_re1_produkt_details ul{
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:auto;
    margin-top:45px;
}

.rf_re1_produkt_details li{
    width:40%; /* Originally it's 50%, but to prevent the whitespace-problem of inline-block here, I adjusted it for a quick and dirty view */
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
}

.rf_re1_produkt_details li:nth-of-type(odd){
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
}

.rf_re1_produkt_details figure{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.rf_re1_produkt_details figure img{
    width: 100%;

}
```

And this is the markup therefore:

```
<section class="rf_re1_produkt_details">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="bilder/fooimg1" />
                <figcaption>Unüberwindliche Weichen</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="bilder/fooimg3.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Zigeunerschnitzel (Oops, Polizei)</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="bilder/fooimg2.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Apfelstrudel</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <img src="bilder/fooimg1.jpg" />
                <figcaption>Foo</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

So, I basically wanna get rid of the white gap between 2 "rows" of li-blocks. How would I do that by not using fixed dimensions to images or figures?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a demo of the output please? Use Jsfiddle or code snippet here.

Comment: if I input your code in codepen I don't get anything like on the picture you provided. Can you add more code for the example to work appropriately

Comment: You need to join whitespaces in the markup because I use inline-block there and wanted to keep it human-readable right here. Or you use something smaller percentage-amounts on  .rf_re1_produkt_details li (like 40%) - 'll update it accordingly in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

On my particular case, I just got aware of the figure-element being too high what caused the gap. I fixed this by - only usable for my particular situation - using a vw-value for the max-height of the figure. Therefore I checked the dimensions of the images and calculated it by the containers' dimensions.